# Any NLP performance timeline?

Tags: computational-linguistics, reference-request

I am looking for any plots, etc. that show performance metrics on various NLP tasks as a function of year.

E.g. [the following figure](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/btl/facial-recognition-technology-shows-improvement/4796) shows the evolution of performance of face recognition systems:

[image]

Comment: Some charts of this nature are available in [Chapter 8](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/routledge/book-7.pdf) of _Using Computers in Linguistics_ (1999). Chapter 8 begins on p.28 of the linked file, which comprises the last two chapters in the book, both dealing with CL/NLP, from different perspectives.